# Dockerignore: allow to add only specific extension like *.json from any subfolder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `.dockerignore` file and I'm trying to allow Docker to upload only `*.json` files but from any of subfolders.

For example, for the next files structure:

```
public/readme.md
public/subfolder/a.json
public/subfolder/b.json
public/other/c.json
public/other/file.txt
```

I'm expecting to see only json files in the image:

```
public/subfolder/a.json
public/subfolder/b.json
public/other/c.json
```

Of course they must be located in the same directories as in original source.

I tried several ways but didn't succeed.

UP: I don't know how many subfolders will be created in the `public/` directory and how deep will be the directories structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by relying on one such .dockerignore:

```
public/*
!public/subfolder
public/subfolder/*
!public/other
public/other/*
!**/*.json
```

The tricky thing is that the first line of this file is `public/*` but not `public` nor `*` (otherwise the `!...` subsequent lines won't work).

Note also that you may want to automate the generation of one such .dockerignore, to cope with possible tree structure changes.

For example:

> gen-dockerignore.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{ echo '*' ;  # header of the .dockerignore - to be changed if need be
  find public -type d -exec echo -en "!{}\n{}/*\n" \; ;
  echo '!**/*.json' ; } > .dockerignore
```

`$ ./gen-dockerignore.sh` would output the following file:

> .dockerignore

```
*
!public
public/*
!public/other
public/other/*
!public/subfolder
public/subfolder/*
!**/*.json
```

Comment: I thought about this variant but I don't know which subfolders will be created during the project development and it would be better to not be locked on their names.

Comment: @kivagant FYI I just added a script example that you can use to automatically update the .dockerignore with respect to the tree structure of your project.